# Async function inside coroutines doesn't work on Android

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, c#-4.0

I'm trying to create a Log In With Facebook flow in my Unity project. 
I'm using Facebook SDK and Firebase to Authenticate and store user data in online DB.

I need to update DB only when the user does not exist there. So I'm using the coroutine

```
    public void someCodeHere(params){
        StartCoroutine(waitForTask(task, uid, name, email));
}

    IEnumerator waitForTask(Task<DataSnapshot> task, string uid, string name, string email)
    {
        while(!task.IsCompleted)
        {
            Debug.Log("Wait task to coplete");
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        }
        Debug.Log(task.Result.GetRawJsonValue());
        if(task.Result.GetRawJsonValue() == null || task.Result.GetRawJsonValue() == "")
        {
            HardUpdateUser(uid, name, email);
        }
        else
        {
            SetExistingUser(task);
        }
    }
```

SetExistingUser works perfectly in Editor and on device,
however HardUpdateUser(uid, name, email); doesn't work on the device but works perfectly in unity editor.

here is the code inside the function:

```
        var status = reference.Child("users").Child(userId).SetRawJsonValueAsync(json).ContinueWith(task =>
        {

            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Debug.LogError("CreateUpdateUserInDB was canceled.");
                return;
            }
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.LogError("CreateUpdateUserInDB encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
                return;
            }
            Debug.LogFormat("User CreateUpdateUserInDB successfully: {0} ({1})",
                user.userName, userId);

        });
```

Comment: When you say "doesn't work on the device", are you getting an error? Have you tried using [Android Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler.html) to get the debug info?

Comment: @EdwinChua, hey, no I haven't tried any tool to get the stack-trace. I'm pretty new with mobile development, I guess I need to figure out how to get the logs. I was also hoped that someone already have had the same blocker

Comment: I've run into this problem a number of times (works on desktop but fails on device), but each time, the solution was different. I had to insert logging at every few steps, to see if the output was what I expected, and debug from there.

Answer (score 1):

So. I haven't get the logs, because I haven't enough time and I guess I was to lazy. 
Anyhow I find some workaround for my issue.

The thing that I haven't mentioned that I start coroutine `StartCoroutine(waitForTask(task, uid, name, email));` inside another coroutine (that of course is inside another courutine). So I have a lot of courutines. And most of them waited for some object from previous function etc. And I use some counter inside while loop. e.g.

```
while(obj == null && wait > 0) {
    wait--; 
    yield return new WaitForSceonds(1);
}
wait = 15;
//run next coroutine
```

and the wait var often was one for few coroutines.
so what I have changed:

1. I'm not waiting for object anymore but for special task to complete
   (e.g. `task.IsCompleted`)
2. I've changed wait var to timestamp. (e.g. I don't want to wait for
   user logged in more than 15 seconds)

So my root problem wasn't in the code that I mentioned in the question.

I'll Update my answer when I'll find some time to investigate Android logs and figure out why  the coroutines got stacked.

here is an example with timestamp:

```
    private IEnumerator SetUserNameToTheTop()
    {
        while (ux.GetCurrentUser() == null && (DateTime.Now - dataTime).TotalSeconds < 15)
        {
            pendingTxt.text = (DateTime.Now - dataTime).TotalSeconds.ToString();
            Debug.Log("WAIT FOR ERROR");
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        }
        if (ux.GetCurrentUser() != null && ux.GetCurrentUser().userName != "")
        {
            ActivateMenu();
        }
        else
        {
            PENDING_MSG = "USER WASN'T FOUND, TRY TO SIGN UP FIRST";
            pendingTxt.text = PENDING_MSG;
            isFailed = true;
            FBButtons.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
```